# Connecting SSAS in another machine via connection string just like connecting a normal server

Tags: ssas, connection-string

So what I'm trying to accomplish here is basically just like an SQL server connection, I want to connect SSAS instance from another computer in the same network using a login account. Things I search online mostly deviates from this a lot at some point. What I need to know is what configurations should I do on SSAS services to enable this? How to crate a new login account (the system I am connecting from is not windows based so no windows authentication) and basically how to build connection string?

I have checked some documents of windows but mostly I am lost.

Answer (score 0):

SSAS clients support NTLM, Kerberos, and (only with the [data pump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0?view=asallproducts-allversions)) HTTP Basic and Anonymous auth.

Of those Kerberos and HTTP Basic (with the data pump) are usable on non-Windows platforms.  But I don't know if ADOMD.NET for .NET Core (the only non-Windows driver) supports Kerberos on non-Windows platforms.